# How to exclude files while zipping folder

Tags: bash, zip

`zip -r --exclude=*.html "${getFilePath('assets')}" "."`

How do I exclude files named "version" and ".htaccess"?
I tried smth. like

`zip -r --exclude=*.html version .htaccess "${getFilePath('assets')}" "."`

but it exclude them viz. image and I can't understand why.

P.S. the "assets" folder above "favicons" folder isn't the one on which I'm performing the command, everything you're seeing is under the another assets file, which is zipped.

[image: Output image]

Comment: "It doesn't work" is rarely a good description. Could you show us a sample input and a sample output, explicit in what way the output does not match your expectations, as well as any error message

Comment: Replace `=` with a space. Take a look at `man zip`.

Comment: `getFilePath('assets')` is not a shell command. Where are you running this?

Comment: From what I see, you are not unzipping an archive, but creating one. Unzipping is done using `unzip`.

Comment: Unzipping was typo, I meant zipping, also I'm running it inside a javascript file, which then pass the whole command to the console.